# front and back face detection

Tags: vector, shadows, lighting

I am trying to implement a dynamic shadow system for a 2d game using this tutorial :

http://www.gamedev.net/page/reference/index.html/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/dynamic-2d-soft-shadows-r2032

but I am stuck at the point where I need to determine which face is front facing or back facing the light source.

[image: light-vector-projection]

Is there a simple technique to apply in order to find out which face is in front and which one is in back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot product of the each face's normal with the vector from the face to the light position should distinguish which faces are front/back.

Comment: Thank you but can you be more explicit? For a square shape, I will have four vector from the light to each points of the shape. Which light vector may I test with which normal vector from the face? For example a square ABCD and light source L, may I do normal(AB).dot(LA) or normal(AB).dot(LB)?

Comment: dot producting with either will suffice I think. Heres a visual of the idea if that helps: [picture](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/6210/dotjw.jpg)

Comment: thank you very much, I understand thanks to your picture